# Thinking NoSql on reference data

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm trying out NoSql and while exploring I can't get into my head on how to deal with reference data. (I'm used to traditional database, the tabular one) Say, I have a School entity which have Students and Requirements. Now, the Student can be enrolled to a School and may comply the Requirements later. So the School would look for a Student and check on which Requirements did he comply.

On traditional database, I would do something like.

```
+---------+  +---------------+ +--------------------+ +---------+
| School  |  | Requirement   | | StudentRequirement | | Student |
+---------+  +---------------+ +--------------------+ +---------+
| Id (PK) |  | Id (PK)       | | Id (PK)            | | Id (PK) |
| Name    |  | Name          | | StudentId (FK)     | | Name    |
+---------+  | SchoolId (FK) | | RequirementId (FK) | +---------+
             +---------------+ | HasComply          |
                               +--------------------+
```

I would create 4 Entities, and the `Requirement` has a many-to-many relationship to a `Student`. So whether I edit or remove a `Requirement` I can just look at the intermediary table.

A flow something like:

```
// EnrollStudentToASchool
// AssignAllRequirementsToNewStudent
```

Then somewhere in my code, if a new requirement was created

```
// IfNewRequirement
// AddNewRequirementToStudent
```

Now, in NoSql and in my case I'm using mongodb, a doc type data store. I read somewhere that data should be inline. Something like:

```
{
  Id: 1,
  School: 'Top1 Foo School',
  Requirements: 
  [
    { Id: 1, Name: 'Req1' },
    { Id: 2, Name: 'Req2' }
  ],
  Students: 
  [
    { 
      Id: 1, 
      Name: 'Student1',
      Requirements:
      [
        { Id: 1, Name: 'Req1', HasComply: false },
        { Id: 2, Name: 'Req2', HasComply: true },
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  Id: 2,
  School: 'Top1 Bar School',
  Requirements: [],
  Students: []
}
```

The root of my document will be the `School`, same flow above:

```
// EnrollStudentToASchool
// AssignAllRequirementsToNewStudent
// IfNewRequirement
// AddNewRequirementToStudent
```

But in case of, say, the School decided to edit the name of the `Requirement` or remove a `Requirement`.

How it should be done? Should I loop all my Students and Edit/Remove the Requirements? Or maybe I'm doing it all wrong.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a nice use case.

Your example brings up most of the relevant pros and cons about converting from sql to noSql.

First please see proposed collection design:
 [image: collection]

We have two collections: `school` and `student` why that? We need to think about bson document size limitation (16MB) and if we have a good school number of students could go over that size.

So why we duplicate data in every student record? If we want to have students details we don't need to go to school (no extra round trip).

We have array of requirements to fulfil in school (a kind of master), and then every student has its own array with result.

Adding / removing such data requires iteration via all students and school.

So in simply words - no join on daily display operations=> efficiency, but update generates a bit more load versus sql.

Any comments welcome!

Comment: Let me know if I understand you correctly. You created 2 collections namely `school` and `student`. You kinda embedded the school details to each student so no extra round trip. Now in case a `requirement` was added/updated/removed from a school, we need to iterate all student and school records. Correct? By the way, thank you so much on putting up the effort for the visual relationship

Comment: Also I notice on the visual representation, you embedded the `requirements` to `student`. Is it for no extra roundtrip? If you were to represent this on a C# class. `public class Student { public int Id { get; set; } public string Name { get; set; } public string SchoolName { get; set; } public ICollection<Requirements> Requirements { get; set; } }` Isn't this a design smell? Or is there some kind of config or mapping beforehand?

Comment: school requirements do not have 'comply', and embeded is school name and id - not all object

Comment: I see. I'm just thinking wont it might be a code smell or something like that if I put some of the properties of the `School` to the `Student` and `School.Requirements` to `Student.Requirements`?

Comment: it is a bit easier to embed school with requirements, but update need to be performed in scholl colection and in student. There is code smell - this is noSql  :-)

Comment: I see. Thank you so much. I think I'm starting to understand NoSql better.

Comment: @BoyPasmo  If my answer helped you please accept it see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Can I ask for your contact email, if there's any questions I have in mind regarding mongodb. I looked at your profile and it seems you're very good at it. Anyway thanks.